# Struggling with using gdb to debug C++ code w/ Ada library

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, gdb, ada

I can't get into the specifics, for a variety of reasons, but here's the essential architecture of what I'm working with

- I have a C++ framework, which uses C++ object files built by me to execute a dynamic simulation.
- The C++ libraries call, among other things, a shared (.so) library, written in Ada.

As best as I can tell, the Ada library (which is a large collection of nontrivial code) is generating exceptions on fringe cases, but I'm having trouble isolating the function that is generating the exception.

Here's what I'm using:

- CentOS 4.8 (Final)
- gcc 3.4.6 (w/ gnat)
- gdb 6.3.0.0-1.162.el4rh

This is the error I get under normal execution:

```
terminate called without an active exception
raised PROGRAM_ERROR : unhandled signal
```

I can get gdb to catch the exception as soon as it returns to the C++, but I can't get it to catch inside the Ada code.  I've made sure to compile everything with `-g`, but that doesn't seem to help the problem.

When I try to catch/break on the signal/exception in `gdb` (which politely tells me `Catch of signal not yet implemented`), I get this:

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New thread -1208371520 (LWP 14568)]
terminate called without an active exception
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to thread -1208371520 (LWP 14568)]
0x001327a2 in _dl_sysinfo_int80 () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

I believe the `terminate called [...]` line is from the framework.  When I try to capture that break, then run a backtrace (`bt`), I get something like this:

```
#0  0x001327a2 in gdb makes me want to flip tables.
#1  0x00661825 in raise () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#2  0x00663289 in abort () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#3  0x0061123e in __gnu_cxx: __verbose_terminate_handler () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x0060eed1 in __xac_call_unexpected () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x0060ef06 in std::terminate () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x0060f0a3 in __xax_rethrow () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x001fe526 in cpputil::ExceptionBase::Rethrow (scope=@0xbfe67470) at ExceptionBase.cpp:140
```

At that point, it's into the framework code.

I've read several guides and tutorials and man pages online, but I'm at a bit of a loss. I'm hoping that someone here can help get me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: What command are you giving gdb to catch the exceptions?

Comment: I tried `catch signal SIGABRT`, but it replied with `Catch of signal not yet implemented.`, so I used `handle SIGABRT stop` to try to catch the signal, but got similar results to above.

I think the real problem, and I don't know how to address this, is that I can't break on uncaught exception in the Ada. When I try `catch exception` (based on some Ada-specific gdb stuff I found online), I get an error, `Unknown event type specified for catch`.

Comment: I believe your GDB needs to be specifically built with Ada support.  I've noticed in my own work that 'catch exception' only works on GDB installs specifically geared toward Ada, such the one distributed by AdaCore.

Comment: This is entirely possible. I'm using whichever version of gdb is included by default on the system. I can set normal breakpoints inside various Ada functions and stop on them consistently, but catching this breakpoint is giving me fits.

Is rebuilding gdb with Ada support something I can do locally, or do I need to get it prebuilt from something like AdaCore?

Comment: You could try breaking at `__gnat_unhandled_exception` (the source is in `s-excdeb.ads`, `s-excdeb.adb`) , which is a "[h]ook called during the propagation process of an exception E, as soon as it is known to be unhandled". This might be too late; `__gnat_debug_raise_exception` is called at the raise point, but will be difficult to use if the application raises many exceptions which it then handles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're able to compile the Ada source code. Assuming that's the case, in the subprogram(s) that are being called through whose execution the exceptions are being raised, add an exception handler at the end that dumps the exception information:

```
when E : others =>
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Ada.Exceptions.Exception_Information(E));
    raise;
```

You'll also need to add a 'with' of Ada.Exceptions to the package.  And Ada.Text_IO if that isn't already present.

I'm not sure exactly what you'll get out from that version of GNAT, but it's probably the invocation addresses which you can then decode using addr2line.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I had to add an `exception` line above this (to fit the `begin`, `exception`, `end` procedure structure), but this let me catch the exception before it got passed to the C++ code and get enough information to follow it to its source.

I haven't solved the problem yet, but I have my first few breadcrumbs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could you start the C++ framework from an Ada main? If so, and you can propagate the exceptions through the C++ framework to the Ada main, its last chance handler ought to give you a pretty good report with exception, source file and line where it occurred, and a stack dump for addr2line. My experience with these is that the debugger usually isn't needed after that.

I could be off beam here because I haven't used a Gnat anywhere near as old as yours...

Comment: I have not tried starting the framework from an Ada main, but I'm not really sure how to do that.  I'm working on a code base that no one on the team completely understands. It doesn't help my Ada-fu is comparatively weak. Do you have a good example for starting the framework from inside an Ada main?

Comment: for example, following this approach - http://wiki.ada-dk.org/c_bindings_example (note : the -fdump-ada-spec binding generator needs gcc4.6 or later, but if you can discover the C++ naming scheme you can create the binding by hand) You presumably only need to call one C++ function. Also : I don't know if C++ would get out of the way and pass on the exceptions intact.

Comment: I have no idea if the framework will let me kick it off with a function call, but I'll dig into the docs tomorrow and see if that's something I can do.

Comment: Alternative might be an Ada wrapper between c++ and library, with exception handling. Not attractive if you need to wrap a few thousand functions...